# Tensorflow - error about tf.WholeFileReader, coordinator, threads, queue

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, queue

I am creating simple code that creates an RGB image in grayscale. Even if this does not work properly, I hope the code will be executed. I have a question about thread usage. Below is the code.

```
with tf.variable_scope("color"): -> make variable(similar to VGG16)
def conv_layer(x, weights, biases, stride, name="convlayer", padding='SAME'):
        return tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(x, weights, strides=stride, padding=padding) + biases, name=name)


    def read_my_file_format(filename_queue, randomize=False):
        reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
        key, file = reader.read(filename_queue)
        uint8image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file, channels=3)
        uint8image = tf.random_crop(uint8image, (224, 224, 3))
        if randomize:
            uint8image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(uint8image)
            uint8image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(uint8image, seed=None)
        float_image = tf.div(tf.cast(uint8image, tf.float32), 255)
        return float_image

    def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs=None):
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
            filenames, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=False)
        example = read_my_file_format(filename_queue, randomize=False)
        min_after_dequeue = 5
        capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
        example_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            [example], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
            min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
        return example_batch

    with tf.name_scope("images_setting"):
        filenames = sorted(glob.glob("C:/example/*.jpg"))
        # filenames = ['C:/example/000005.jpg', 'C:/example/000007.jpg ~~~~']
        batch_size = 2
        num_epochs = 100

        colorimage = input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs=num_epochs)
        grayscale = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(colorimage)

    with tf.name_scope("layer_explain"):
        expand = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(grayscale)
        conv1_1 = conv_layer(expand, conv1_1_weights, conv1_1_biases, stride1, 'conv1_1')
        conv1_2 = conv_layer(conv1_1, conv1_2_weights, conv1_2_biases, stride1, 'conv1_2')

        conv2_1 = conv_layer(conv1_2, conv2_1_weights, conv2_1_biases, stride1, 'conv2_1')
        conv2_2 = conv_layer(conv2_1, conv2_2_weights, conv2_2_biases, stride1, 'conv2_2')

        conv3_1 = conv_layer(conv2_2, conv3_1_weights, conv3_1_biases, stride1, 'conv3_1')
        conv3_2 = conv_layer(conv3_1, conv3_2_weights, conv3_2_biases, stride1, 'conv3_2')
        conv3_3 = conv_layer(conv3_2, conv3_3_weights, conv3_3_biases, stride1, 'conv3_3')

        conv4_1 = conv_layer(conv3_3, conv4_1_weights, conv4_1_biases, stride1, 'conv4_1')
        conv4_2 = conv_layer(conv4_1, conv4_2_weights, conv4_2_biases, stride1, 'conv4_2')
        conv4_3 = conv_layer(conv4_2, conv4_3_weights, conv4_3_biases, stride1, 'conv4_3')

        conv5_1 = conv_layer(conv4_3, conv5_1_weights, conv5_1_biases, stride1, 'conv5_1')
        conv5_2 = conv_layer(conv5_1, conv5_2_weights, conv5_2_biases, stride1, 'conv5_2')
        conv5_3 = conv_layer(conv5_2, conv5_3_weights, conv5_3_biases, stride1, 'conv5_3')


    print("conv5_3: ", conv5_3)
    print("colorimage: ", colorimage)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(conv5_3 - colorimage))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
    opt = optimizer.minimize(loss)


    init_global = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    init_local = tf.local_variables_initializer()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init_global)
    sess.run(init_local)

    # Start input enqueue threads.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    print("expand: ", expand)
    print("conv1_1: ", conv1_1)

    print("grayscale: ", grayscale)
    print(filenames, '**********************')
    try:
        while not coord.should_stop():
            training_opt = sess.run(opt)

            for i in range(10):
                loss = sess.run(loss)
                print("cost: {}".format(loss))
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        print("Done training -- epoch limit reached")
    finally:
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
```

Error message:

> (cost: 0.2219611406326294)
>
> Fetch argument 0.22196114 has invalid type
>   , must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert
>   a float32 into a Tensor or Operation.)
>   --> This is error... I think the message means something wrong at "loss funcion"
>
> (Done training -- epoch limit reached)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the following line:

```
                loss = sess.run(loss)
```

The first time it runs, `loss` is a Tensor, so when session.run returns its value, the python variable `loss` is not a python float, which you cannot pass to session.run.

Do instead something like

```
            loss_value = sess.run(loss)
```

and you'll be fine.